# Creating Table: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am getting the ORA-00936: missing expression error message when creating a table in SQL using the following command. Any ideas where I'm tripping up?

```
CREATE TABLE Workorders (
    Wo# VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    Proj# VARCHAR2(8) REFERENCES Project (Proj#),
    Wo_desc VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Wo_assigned CHAR(40),
    Wo_hours NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CHECK(>0),
    Wo_start DATE,
    Wo_due DATE,
    Wo_complete CHECK (Wo_complete IN ('Y','N')));
```

Comment: Take a look at this line `Wo_hours NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CHECK(>0),` and this one `Wo_complete CHECK (Wo_complete IN ('Y','N')));`

Comment: Are commas required between multiple constraints? Or am I doing the CHECK wrong?

Comment: 1. Column name is missing in the check constraint definition. 2. Column's data type is missing

Comment: Just figured it out. Wo_complete needed a datatype. I gave it CHAR(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can't define check constraints like that, you need the column name in the check:

```
CREATE TABLE Workorders (
    Wo# VARCHAR2(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    Proj# VARCHAR2(8) REFERENCES Project (Proj#),
    Wo_desc VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Wo_assigned CHAR(40),
    Wo_hours NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL CHECK ( wo_hours > 0 ),
    Wo_start DATE,
    Wo_due DATE,
    Wo_complete CHAR(1) CHECK (Wo_complete IN ('Y','N') )
);
```

Comment: In testing, I created the Project table and made the `Proj#` a primary key.  After executing your DDL, when I look at the `references` constraint, it creates the constraint, `FOREIGN KEY ("PROJ#") REFERENCES "SCOTT"."PROJECT" ("PROJ#")`

Comment: @PatrickBacon I am confused as to the point you are trying to convey with your comment. Can you elaborate as to its relevance?

Comment: I agree to your syntax, though I find it interesting that the op did not explicitly call this out as a foreign key constraint.